# change div display after get or post

Tags: javascript, html

I have several divs. One of them is:

```
    <div id="content1" style="display:none;">
```

So, at first, this div won't show.

```
function pass(name){
window.location.href="index.php?ownerid="+name;
document.getElementById("content1").style.display="initial";
}
```

As the code above, I want show "content1" after get "ownerid", then set display to "initial". But it doesn't work. Is there any methods to realize my idea? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited:*

Since your reloading the page your javascript changes won't persist. You have to check for the ownerid on page load itself:

```
var ownerid = location.search.match(/ownerid=(\w+)/);
if(ownerid && ownerid[1]) {
  document.getElementById("content1").style.display="initial";
}
```

Here, `location.search` will give you the query string i.e. `?ownerid=value`. Next `match(/ownerid=(\w+)/)` will give an array of ownerid parameter and its value `["ownerid=value","value"]`, in-case parameters is missing it gives you null.

Comment: my mistake, div id  should be "content1".  But it doesn't work because of reload the page, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Once the page is reloaded the change in visibility of the div won't change. You could instead check when the page is loaded if the `ownerid` param is set and use that to determine the visibility of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Your not using the correct `id` of your `<div>`, Try this :

```
document.getElementById("div1").style.display="initial";
```

Comment: div id should be "content1", I have changed it in my question. The problem is that window.location will renew the page......